# I want to invoke Webview.loadRequest() multiple times in Swift3

Tags: ios, swift3

I am new to IOS development. And I am working to get page load time of web on IOS emulators.

Since, I am targeting top 100 alexa websites, it would be difficult to load each url and record time for load. So, I am planning to automate it.

Below is my code:

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate{

```
var startTime = Date()
@IBOutlet weak var WebView: UIWebView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    // let URL = Foundation.URL(string: "http://www.youtube.com")
    startTime = Date()
    print(startTime)
    for url in returnURLArray(){
        WebView.delegate = self
        WebView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!))
        print("I am trying to load...."+url)
        sleep(100)
        print("back to execute other urls")

    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ WebView: UIWebView)
{


    //Check here if still webview is loding the content
    if (WebView.isLoading){
        print("I am loading now...")
        return;
    }

    //after code when webview finishes
    let finishTime = Date()
    print(finishTime.timeIntervalSince(startTime))
    NSLog("Webview loding finished")
}

func returnURLArray() -> [String] {
    let file = "topalexawebsites.txt" //this is the file. we will write to and read from it
    var text2 = String()
    var urlArr = [String]()
    if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
        let path = dir.appendingPathComponent(file)
        do{
            print(path)
            text2 = try String(contentsOf: path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8).trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
            urlArr = text2.components(separatedBy: "\n")

            // print(text2)
            // for urls in urlArr{
            //   print(urls)
            //}

        }
        catch let err as NSError{
            print(err)

        }

    }
    return urlArr

}
```

}

I want to execute all urls one by one in my topalexawebsites.txt and record load time for it.
But, here I am seeing only one cycle is working, and since urls are in  a loop, only the also one gets loaded.

Comment: you are calling sleep(100) on main thread. In your case webview is NOT loading page. Please read about main thread and NSOperations.

Comment: I was only adding sleep(100), so that after loadRequest invocation, it gets some time to call pageLoadDidFinish() and then start with another URL. bUt, it urned out, it does not work this way. Will sure read on NSOperations. Thanks.

Comment: Create a tracking `Int`, and in `webViewDidFinishLoad ` run the next url in the array until it reach 100, calculate time from `didStartLoad` to `didFinishLoad` and reset

Comment: will try and post here. Thank you so much @Tj3n

Comment: Does not help, as the loop is first increasing counts and then only some pages with higher latency are going to webpagedidStartLoad().